# In Grails, is there a good way to mock the current time using Joda time?

Tags: grails, time, groovy, mocking, jodatime

I'm writing some code that does date and time calculations against the current time. In Joda time, this is accessed through a (Java) constructor, as it is an immutable object. I need to be able to mock so that `new DateTime()` returns a specific constant instant so I can do sensible test assertions, but leave all other DateTime methods alone.

This is proving nasty. Grails `mockFor(DateTime, true)` won't let me mock a Java constructor, yet there is no obvious or readable non-constructor way of getting the time in Joda time.

The only available options seem to involve low-level JVM techniques like JMockit or EasyMock 3 class mocking, which are a pain from Grails. Is there a simple/straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We ended up creating `dateService` with `now()` method. In unit tests we mock it with

```
domainInstance.dateService = [ now: { currentTime } ] as DateService
```

where `currentTime` is a unit test class field. This imposes everybody's dependency on `dateService` (our only nearly-global dependency), and for `src` classes one has to pass it by hand.

Unit tests, OTOH, look pretty clear with it.

Comment: Great answer. I had kind of been hoping to avoid architecting the system differently just to make this test possible, but I've learned a lot about how painful it can be to mock constructors.

Comment: Thanks. I try to avoid direct constructor invocation - it violates "code for interface", the instance created can't be externalized like in tests, and sometimes leads to `Construction Blobs`. So it boiled down to a form of dependency injection.

Answer (score 19):

I know this as already been accepted, but with Joda-time you can freeze and set it to be whatever you like.  So you can freeze time, advance time, go backwards in time.  Provided you're using Joda consistently, your objects will get "now" as whatever time you've set that to be.

```
// Stop time (and set a particular point in time):
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(whenever);

// Advance time by the offset:
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisOffset(offsetFromCurrent);

// Restore time (you could do this in an @After method)
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem();
```

Comment: Oooh neat, I had been hoping for something like this. This will make testing much easier. Great tip!!

Comment: Now I feel stupid, because we're on Joda. It's a better way. Good, I learned something.

Answer (score 2):

you could just use good old-fashioned OO principles, e.g.

```
  interface TimeService {
    DateTime getCurrentTime()

    // other time-related methods
  }

  class JodaTimeService implements TimeService {
    DateTime getCurrentTime() {
      new DateTime()
    }  
  }

  class MockTimeService implements TimeService {
    DateTime getCurrentTime() {
      // return a fixed point in time
    }  
  }
```

Your code should get a reference to an implementation of `TimeService` via dependency injection. In `resources.groovy` use the `MockTimeService` only when running the tests

```
import grails.util.Environment

beans = {    
    if (Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
        timeService(MockTimeService)

    } else {
         timeService(JodaTimeService)
    }
}
```

Comment: Independently the same approach as above, so many thanks, and a good solution worked through in depth. And extra thanks for the hints about using the test environment to switch.