# Groovy/Grails equivalent of Ruby/Rails' 'timecop' gem

Tags: ruby, grails, groovy, timecop

does anybody know if there is something for Groovy/Grails similar to the [**rubygem timecop**](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)

I'm working on tests for a Grails project where I would like to mock DateTime classes in the same way the gem does.

Just wondering if anybody had already done it with a Grails plugin or something similar so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Might be related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130838/in-grails-is-there-a-good-way-to-mock-the-current-time-using-joda-time

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same as Timecop but the [Timetravel plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-timetravel) provides a feature to define the date for the automatically generated `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` fields in domain classes.

Regards, Iván.